# machine-learning method to predict PCA weights

Tags: programming, machine-learning, pca

I have been using certain linear-regression to extract the PCA (top 3) weights relating to a certain data-set.
I was wondering, instead of using linear-regression to generate the weights, I can use machine-learning (from python skLearn) to extract the weights.

My block below is how I traditionally extract the weights.

```
eigVal, eigVec = scipy.linalg.eig(data_.cov())

results_ = []
for cnt in range(len(data_)):
    y_ = (data_.iloc[cnt].values)
    a1, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(eigVec[:,0][:,np.newaxis], y_)
    a2, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(eigVec[:,1][:,np.newaxis], y_)
    a3, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(eigVec[:,2][:,np.newaxis], y_)
    mv_pca = a1 * eigVec[:,0] + a2 * eigVec[:,1] + a3* eigVec[:,2]
    mv_abs = np.sum(abs(y_))
    mv_err = np.sum(abs((mv_pca - y_)))
    results_.append([data_.index[cnt], a1.real[0], a2.real[0], a3.real[0], mv_abs, mv_err])
```

this block below is how I am trying to use a few different learning techniques to extract the weights. Two problems I face is that,

- the learning code can only handle integers (hence, the need to
  digitize the continuous variables).
- I am not sure how to handle what
  are essentially a vector for each PCA, when machine-learning takes
  only one (integer) variable for each input state.

This is the block code below

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB # gaussian process machine learning https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html
from sklearn import tree # Decision Trees (DTs) are a non-parametric supervised learning method used for classification and regression. 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier # random forest tree machine learning
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier # K nearest neighbour
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors # nearest neighbour

from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_diabetes() # load pseudo test data

l_time = []


bins1 = np.linspace(np.min(wt_.wt1)*0.95, np.max(wt_.wt1)*1.05, 20)
bins2 = np.linspace(np.min(wt_.wt2)*0.95, np.max(wt_.wt2)*1.05, 20)
bins3 = np.linspace(np.min(wt_.wt3)*0.95, np.max(wt_.wt3)*1.05, 20)
bins_Target = np.linspace(np.min(data_.EUR10Y)*0.95, np.max(data_.EUR10Y)*1.05, 20)
dig_1 = np.digitize(wt_.wt1, bins1)
dig_2 = np.digitize(wt_.wt2, bins2)
dig_3 = np.digitize(wt_.wt3, bins3)
dig_T = np.digitize(data_.EUR10Y, bins_Target)

ml_data = pd.DataFrame([dig_1, dig_2, dig_3]).T.values # generate the input vectors of PCA weights
ml_target = dig_T # set the target to be predicted to the EUR 10y swap rate
fl_data = ml_data[0:1200] # initialize the first 200 data points
fl_target = ml_target[0:1200]
columns = ['wt1', 'wt2', 'wt3']

start_time = time.time()
SKgnb_pred = GaussianNB().fit(ml_data, ml_target).predict(fl_data)
print("gnb --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print("Number of mislabeled points out of a total %d points : %d" % (fl_data.shape[0],(fl_target != SKgnb_pred).sum()))
l_time.append(['gnb', 1000 * (time.time() - start_time)])

start_time = time.time()
SKdtr_pred = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(ml_data, ml_target).predict(fl_data)
print("dtr --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print("Number of mislabeled points out of a total %d points : %d" % (fl_data.shape[0],(fl_target != SKdtr_pred).sum()))
l_time.append(['dtr', 1000 * (time.time() - start_time)])

start_time = time.time()
SKftr_pred = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators= len(ml_data), max_depth= len(columns), random_state= None).fit(ml_data, ml_target).predict(fl_data)
print("ftr --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print("Number of mislabeled points out of a total %d points : %d" % (fl_data.shape[0],(fl_target != SKftr_pred).sum()))
l_time.append(['ftr', 1000 * (time.time() - start_time)])

start_time = time.time()
SKknn_pred = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1, algorithm='ball_tree', metric = 'euclidean').fit(ml_data, ml_target).predict(fl_data)
print("knn --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print("Number of mislabeled points out of a total %d points : %d" % (fl_data.shape[0],(fl_target != SKknn_pred).sum()))
l_time.append(['knn', 1000 * (time.time() - start_time)])

start_time = time.time()
SKsgd_pred = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", penalty="l2", max_iter= 100).fit(ml_data, ml_target).predict(fl_data) # stochastic gradient descent
print("sgd --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print("Number of mislabeled points out of a total %d points : %d" % (fl_data.shape[0],(fl_target != SKsgd_pred).sum()))
l_time.append(['sgd', 1000 * (time.time() - start_time)])

SK_target = pd.DataFrame(fl_target, columns = ['target'])
SK_data = pd.DataFrame(fl_data, columns = columns)

SKgnb_pred = pd.DataFrame(SKgnb_pred, columns = ['pred_gnb'])
SKdtr_pred = pd.DataFrame(SKdtr_pred, columns = ['pred_dtr'])
SKftr_pred = pd.DataFrame(SKftr_pred, columns = ['pred_ftr'])
SKknn_pred = pd.DataFrame(SKknn_pred, columns = ['pred_knn'])
SKsgd_pred = pd.DataFrame(SKsgd_pred, columns = ['pred_sgd'])

SK_all = SK_data.merge(SK_target, left_index = True, right_index = True).merge(SKknn_pred, left_index = True, right_index = True)
SK_all = SK_all.merge(SKdtr_pred, left_index = True, right_index = True).merge(SKftr_pred, left_index = True, right_index = True).merge(SKgnb_pred, left_index = True, right_index = True)
SK_all = SK_all.merge(SKsgd_pred, left_index = True, right_index = True)

SK_all.head()
```

Comment: I don't really understand why you are using least squares to solve the PC multipliers, rather than using the explicit formulae, can you mathematically describe the theory? Besides that it is my personal opinion that somewhat complicated code blocks without comments and or necessary references are not particularly appealing questions since the reader has to do a lot of deciphering before tackling the problem.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, both OLS and eigenvalue decomposition are O(N^3).  Why approximate the problem when there exists an exact result?